# Office Javascript API. Issue when moving row to another sheet

Tags: javascript, excel, office-js, exceljs

I've created a little function that moves a row to another worksheet using Office javascript api and run into a little problem. I'm identifying all rows with strikethrough text and then moving them to an archive sheet. The issue appears to be with the line

```
dataRange.getRow(row).moveTo(targetSheet.getRange("A" + tglastrowindex));
```

If this line is commented out then the variable tglastrowindex correctly increments in each iteration of the for loop but if the line is enabled the row moves correctly but tglastrowindex variable does not increment so it overwrites the row instead of adding after the last row of the archive sheet.

Not exactly sure what's causing it but possibly something to do with the row moving? Has anyone run into this before or can help with a solution?

```
async function archive() {
    await Excel.run(async (context) => {
      worksheet = context.workbook.worksheets.getActiveWorksheet();
      await context.sync();
      console.log("archiving");
      let myUsedRange = worksheet.getUsedRange();
      let lastrow = myUsedRange.getLastRow().load(["rowindex", "values"]);
      await context.sync();
      let lastrowindex = lastrow.rowIndex + 1;

      //console.log(JSON.stringify(lastrow.rowIndex + 1, null, 4));

      let dataRange = worksheet.getRange("A5:M" + lastrowindex).load(["rowCount", "rowIndex"]);
      await context.sync();
      
      var tglastrowindex = 0;
      var targetSheet;
      var tgUsedRange;
      var tglastrow;
      var cnt = 0;

      for (var row = 0; row < dataRange.rowCount; row++) {
        //dataRange.getRow(row).format.fill.clear();
        //console.log("tglastrowindex1:" + tglastrowindex);
        let dataCell = dataRange.getCell(row, 1).load(["format/font/strikethrough"]);
        await context.sync();

        //console.log(JSON.stringify(dataCell, null, 4));
          
        if (dataCell.format.font.strikethrough == true) {
          //console.log("strikethrough detected");
          worksheet.load("name");
          await context.sync();
          //console.log("sourcesheetname:" + worksheet.name);
          if (worksheet.name == "Sheet1") {
            //console.log("worksheet detected");
            targetSheet = context.workbook.worksheets.getItem("Archive").load("name");
            await context.sync();
            //console.log("targetsheet name:" + targetSheet.name);        
            tgUsedRange = targetSheet.getUsedRange();                      
            tglastrow = tgUsedRange.getLastRow().load(["rowindex", "values"]);
            await context.sync();             
            if(cnt == 0){
              tglastrowindex = tglastrow.rowIndex + 1;
              cnt = cnt + 1;
            }
            else {
              tglastrowindex = tglastrowindex + 1;
            }                                            
            console.log("targetsheet index:" + tglastrowindex);
                      
            
            dataRange.getRow(row).moveTo(targetSheet.getRange("A" + tglastrowindex));   
            
          }                 
                          
        }            
      }
      
    });
```

Comment: Can you reproduce this in the Script Lab tool? If so, please export a gist and provide a link to the gist.

Answer (score 1):

First off, I'd upvote question but it does not include a "create data" code example so we can both create the data and then create the problem.

See --> https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Another example where I created example data in the question --> [Custom Sort Column - Excel Javascript - Office-JS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76167871/custom-sort-column-excel-javascript-office-js)

As well, in regards to your code, I see a lot of `context.sync` and that is to be avoided, especially inside loops. Unfortunately, there is no way to load individual cell format properties inside a range, so you have to batch up `load` calls for each individual cell. I didn't test this code w/ say >50K rows, but you will run into issues if your workbook is that big and need to batch the syncs and loop the entire code below where it builds the `st_rows_arr_of_ri` array.

See --> [Get individual cell formats in Excel using office.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35647790/get-individual-cell-formats-in-excel-using-office-js)

One issue that stood out to me in regards to your question was your usage of the range formatting convention of `A1`. Try to use numbers ONLY when using ranges, so `getRangeByIndexes` for example. You should only need to find the last row of the `Archive` worksheet once before you start writing to it, then you can keep track of the `lastrow` in memory and increment without checking/syncing each loop/write.

Here is some example code I ended up with that is how I would tackle the above issue as a whole. Pretty generic, I didn't delete the lines from the existing worksheet, you'd likely want to do that in reverse if so and I have external functions for some of the code below, but I built it all in one for this example.

```
var ws = context.workbook.worksheets.getActiveWorksheet();

//Create fake data
ws.getRange("A1:C10").values = "TEST" 
ws.getRange("A2:C2").format.font.strikethrough = true
ws.getRange("A10:C10").format.font.strikethrough = true
await context.sync()

//Get UsedRng rowCount/Index
var Used_Rng_And_Props = ws.getUsedRange(true);
var load_opts_arr = [
    "rowCount",
    "rowIndex",
];
Used_Rng_And_Props.load(load_opts_arr)
await context.sync();

//Sync up cell formats array
var cell_formats_arr = []
//https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35647790/get-individual-cell-formats-in-excel-using-office-js
var load_opts_arr = [
    "format/font/strikethrough",
    "rowIndex",
]
for (let ri = Used_Rng_And_Props.rowIndex; ri < Used_Rng_And_Props.rowCount; ri++) {
    cell_formats_arr.push(ws.getRangeByIndexes(ri, 0, 1, 1).load(load_opts_arr))
}
await context.sync()

//Get all row indexes w/ cells in Column 0 with strikethrough text
var st_rows_arr_of_ri = []
for (let ai = 0; ai < cell_formats_arr.length; ai++) {
    var cell = cell_formats_arr[ai]
    if (cell.format.font.strikethrough == true) {
        st_rows_arr_of_ri.push(cell.rowIndex)
    }
}
var cell_formats_arr = null

//Get Dest Sheet and add Fake Data
var targetSheet = context.workbook.worksheets.add("archive")
targetSheet.getRange("A1:A3").values = "FakeExistingData"
await context.sync()

//Get Dest Sheet Last Row
var targetSheet_Used_Rng_And_Props = targetSheet.getUsedRange(true)
var load_opts_arr = [
    "rowCount",
    "rowIndex",
];
targetSheet_Used_Rng_And_Props.load(load_opts_arr)
await context.sync()
var row_ct = targetSheet_Used_Rng_And_Props.rowIndex + targetSheet_Used_Rng_And_Props.rowCount

//Move Data
for (let ai = 0; ai < st_rows_arr_of_ri.length; ai++) {
    var ri = st_rows_arr_of_ri[ai]
    console.log('ri: ' + ri)
    var src_rng = ws.getUsedRange(true).getRow(ri)
    var dst_rng = targetSheet.getRangeByIndexes(row_ct, 0, 1, 1) //Use getRangeByIndexes to remove need for row 0 check for A1 rng format
    src_rng.moveTo(dst_rng);
    row_ct = row_ct + 1
}
await context.sync()
```

Comment: This works much better thanks.. It doesn't seem to move the first instance of the strikethrough text though? It does move the rest & much faster than looping through

Comment: this was because 1st row of sheet was blank

Comment: @user552769 Did this resolve your issue? Please accept if so.